# Cómo mostrar JSON en un TextView usando Retrofit y JAVA

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, post

estoy teniendo problemas con mostrar parte de mi json

```
**{
    "MQ0302A_DATAREQ": {
    "tableId": "VMQ03421",
    "rowset": [
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 26,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622682,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "17/11/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 34,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622634,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "29/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622626,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622625,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622628,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622623,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622624,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622718,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "29/11/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622630,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622683,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "19/11/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622629,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622627,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 2,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 15187,
            "ORDEN": 622578,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "T.A.E.S.A. AGRIC. GANADERA",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "18/10/2021"
        }
    ],
    "records": 13,
    "moreRecords": false
},
"jde__status": "SUCCESS",
"jde__startTimestamp": "2022-03-16T15:27:09.593-0300",
"jde__endTimestamp": "2022-03-16T15:27:09.749-0300",
"jde__serverExecutionSeconds": 0.156
```

}
**

sin problemas puedo  recuperar esto ultimo

```
     "jde__status": "SUCCESS",
     "jde__startTimestamp": "2022-03-16T15:27:09.593-0300",
     "jde__endTimestamp": "2022-03-16T15:27:09.749-0300",
     "jde__serverExecutionSeconds": 0.156
```

y puedo obtener un código exitoso de código 200

lo que realmente quiero de este json es:

```
{
        "CANTIDAD": 26,
        "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
        "ORDEN": 622682,
        "TIPO": "SO",
        "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
        "DEPOSITO": "          01",
        "FECHA": "17/11/2021"
    },
```

}...

les agradecería un montón ya que estoy trabado hace un tiempo...

sé que tengo que crear un Arraylist ya que "rowset" esta con "["

así que lo primero que hice fue serializar todo:

```
   public class LoginUser {
    @SerializedName("jde__status")
    @Expose
   private String jdeStatus;
   @SerializedName("jde__startTimestamp")
   @Expose
   private String jdeStartTimestamp;
   @SerializedName("jde__endTimestamp")
   @Expose
   private String jdeEndTimestamp;
   @SerializedName("jde__serverExecutionSeconds")
   @Expose
   private Double jdeServerExecutionSeconds;

   getters and setters...
```

cómo necesitaba agregarle una validación de usuario, contraseña y deposito para poder recuperar los datos le agregué más

y me quedó así

```
public class LoginUser {

@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;

@SerializedName("deposito")
@Expose
private String deposito;



constructor


getters y setters



@SerializedName("jde__status")
@Expose
private String jdeStatus;
@SerializedName("jde__startTimestamp")
@Expose
private String jdeStartTimestamp;
@SerializedName("jde__endTimestamp")
@Expose
private String jdeEndTimestamp;
@SerializedName("jde__serverExecutionSeconds")
@Expose
private Double jdeServerExecutionSeconds;

getters y setters
```

2- armé la clase del objeto "MQ0302A_DATAREQ"

```
   public class Mq0302aDatareq {

   @SerializedName("tableId")
   @Expose
   private String tableId;
   @SerializedName("rowset")
   @Expose
   private ArrayList<Rowset> rowset = null;
   @SerializedName("records")
   @Expose
   private Integer records;
   @SerializedName("moreRecords")
   @Expose
   private Boolean moreRecords;
   getters y setters
```

y finalmente la clase dónde esta lo que quiero recuperar

```
public class Rowset {


@SerializedName("CANTIDAD")
@Expose
private int cantidad;
@SerializedName("NRO_CLIENTE")
@Expose
private int nroCliente;
@SerializedName("ORDEN")
@Expose
private int orden;
@SerializedName("TIPO")
@Expose
private String tipo;
@SerializedName("CLIENTE")
@Expose
private Integer cliente;
@SerializedName("DEPOSITO")
@Expose
private Integer deposito;
@SerializedName("FECHA")
@Expose
private String fecha;

getters and setters
```

3- construí un API para la conexión de usuario y y otro para recuperar el json

```
 public interface Conexion {
@POST("jderest/v3/orchestrator/MQ0302A_ORCH")
Call<LoginUser> getUser(@Body LoginUser users );

@POST("jderest/v3/orchestrator/MQ0302A_ORCH")
Call <ArrayList<Rowset>> getData(@Body Rowset users );
```

aclaro por las dudas que en mi body tengo el usuario, contraseña y deposito
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyh0i.png)

4-después armé mi MainActivity

```
 public void Logearse(View v) {

    String user2 = user.getText().toString();
    String contraseña2 = contraseña.getText().toString();

    if (user2.length() == 0 && contraseña2.length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Debes ingresar un usuario y contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (user2.length() != 0 && contraseña2.length() != 0) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Procesando", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    //conexión
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(" http://137.116.116.34:91/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Conexion conexion = retrofit.create(Conexion.class);

    String userName = user2;
    String password = contraseña2;

    LoginUser logerse = new LoginUser(userName, password, desposito);

    Call<LoginUser> call = conexion.getUser(logerse);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginUser> call, Response<LoginUser> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                informeConexion.setText("code: " + response.code() + " Conexión exitosa " + "\n");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Succefully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  
       }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginUser> call, Throwable t) {
            informeConexion.setText(t.getMessage());

        }

   });

}
```

hasta este punto me dió todo bien, quise agregar adentro del metodo de LoginUser otra llamada pero no tuve éxito

```
  Call<ArrayList<Rowset>> call2 = conexion.getData(login);
                            call2.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Rowset>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call <ArrayList<Rowset>> call, Response <ArrayList<Rowset>> response) {
                                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                        informeConexion.setText("code: " + response.code() + " Conexión exitosa " + "\n");




                                        ArrayList<Rowset> postResponse = (ArrayList<Rowset>) response.body();
                                        String content = "";
                                        content += "" + postResponse.getCantidad() + "\n";
                                        prueba.setText(content);

                                        String content1 = "";
                                        content1 += "" + postResponse.getDeposito() + "\n";
                                        prueba3.setText(content1);

                                        String content2 = "";
                                        content2 += "" + postResponse.getFecha()+ "\n\n";
                                        prueba4.setText(content2);

                                        
                                    }else {
                                 }
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call <ArrayList<Rowset>> call, Throwable t) {

                                }
                            });
```

Tengo entendido que me faltaría agregar un adaptador, traté de encontrar uno parecido, pero en verdad estoy perdido en cómo hacerlo, desde ya muchas gracias gente!

Comment: Le indicas que va a devolver un arraylist de rowset, pero en realidad el json que obtienes no es un array de rowset... debes indicarle el modelo exacto que vas a recibir para que pueda encontrar el rowset, lo que recibes no es ni siquiera tu objeto `Mq0302aDatareq`, si no un objeto que tiene dentro a tu objeto `Mq0302aDatareq` y más. Si te cuesta entender cómo pasar de json a java, busca en google "json to java pojo" y hay un montón de utilidades que te generarán las clases necesarias

Comment: Hola @Benito-B! gracias por contestar!
ahora mismo buscaré, yo a la serializacion lo habia hecho con https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ por eso determiné que era un arrayList

Comment: Si, la parte del rowset es efectivamente una lista (o un array, o un arraylist... en fin, una colección de ese tipo). Pero no puedes intentar que te devuelva solo eso si eso en realidad está anidado en otro objeto. Necesitas todo el objeto (el "wrapper") para poder obtener los objetos anidados. Java no va a navegar el json por ti, lo más fácil es pasarlo todo a clases de java y luego obtener exactamente lo que necesitas. Pero para eso debes modelar **todo** el json, no solo la parte anidada que te interesa...

Comment: ah por eso solo me recupera la primera parte? cómo no lo estoy armando bien a la llamada del json... ok, bueno igual sigo un poco perdido donde continuar, sé que la primera parte me recupera, entonces deberia encontrar la forma que entre por el **Mq0302aDatareq** recupere lo que tiene adentro y despues entre por *rowset*.
asi que bueno seguiré viendo foros, porque aun estoy perdido igual gracias

Comment: G. Capovi el problema que tienes es que el json contiene un objeto y dentro del objeto esta la lista de items(rowset). Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un Objeto que incluya las variables tableId,records y las que necesites, luego en ese mismo objeto crear la variable ArrayList<RowSet> rowset; en esa lista se guardara el detalle de cada item.
Te recomiendo que uses GsonConverterFactory en tu retrofit para ayudar con la conversión.
https://square.github.io/retrofit/